# Getting off of Cox's blacklist

Tags: email, blacklist

I'm working for a company that sells hosted CRM services, and as such we send a *ton* of email. We've done a lot of work over the past few years to tighten up the way we send email [double opt-in, bounce tracking, FBL processing, client education, etc] and our reputation has been relatively fine.

However, we recently migrated to a new batch of hardware with new IPs and have found that Cox is permanently deferring our email with a [CXBL](http://postmaster.cox.net/confluence/display/postmaster/Error+Codes) response. We've tried contacting Cox through their postmaster form *several* times over the past weeks, but have not received any response.

Now I've not seen anything ominous in either abuse reports or FBL messages for our relays, so I don't think we have a rogue/hacked client sending out spam, and the traffic ramp-up from these new relay IPs should have happened over the course of a month. I've also run the IPs through a thorough [blacklist check](http://multirbl.valli.org/) to make sure we didn't inherit someone else's problem.

I simply cannot understand why Cox refuses to contact us regarding this issue. Does anyone have some advice on how to get through to them? Is there a phone number for their email admins or a secret phrase I need to slip into my next email?

Comment: Don't start at the bottom rung with an employee who's hands are tied by a policy book and does not care about anything but keeping their numbers up. Start somewhere else. Sometimes Marketing can really help- sounds odd- but they would be the most sympathetic and may be able to pass a message or get an answer. Speak to them from a business marketing perspective. Sometimes a VP can help. I have called CEOs several times and have quite a few as friends as a result. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I realise that this is a 2015 question and that it has probably been resolved internally already but for others who encounter the same issue in the future...

Cox does reply back even if the decision is to not unblock. Sometimes unblocking can take a while to decide, especially if there has been a large number of unblock requests made at the same time by others. If the unblock is more urgent as @closetnoc says you can try contacting the marketing department to get through to someone more urgently or you can try calling them up to see if you can speak to someone but often with companies like this you need to just wait until the make the decision in their own time.